# How do I get H2 and SpringBoot to play nice together using the in memory database?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, h2

I'm working my way through a tutorial video on unit testing with JUnit and Mockito and have run across some issues where something isn't playing nice and I'm trying to figure out the problem.  The tutorial is creating an in memory database using H2 which is where I am having issues (the database has no data).  I have created a new project with the sole purpose of creating the same database which works to a point and then fails with no data.  After a couple days of research I'm hoping someone will see something glaringly obvious that I'm missing.  I'm using IntelliJ Idea 21.1.2 as my IDE, Linux Mint OS.  H2 is new to me.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestH2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>TestH2</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:item;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

schema.sql

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ITEM;

CREATE TABLE ITEM (
    id INT,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    price INT,
    quantity INT
);
```

data.sql

```
INSERT INTO ITEM(id, name, price, quantity)
VALUES
       (10001,'Item1',10,20),
       (10002,'Item2',5,10),
       (10003,'Item3',15,2);
```

With the above and my application file the project builds and when I open the h2-console I get the expected result.
[image: H2 console works as expected]

However. . .

If I try to add an Item.java file like this (note if I comment out the @Entity line it works as shown above)

```
package com.example.testh2.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

@Entity
public class Item {

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int price;
    private int quantity;

    @Transient
    private int value;

    public Item() {

    }

    public Item(int id, String name, int price, int quantity) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.quantity = quantity;

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public int getValue() { return value; }
    public void setValue(int value) { this.value = value; }


    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Item[%d, %s, %d, %d]", id, name, price, quantity);
    }


}
```

Then there is no data

[image: H2 fails]

I'm guessing that I'm missing something simple, I just haven't Google'd the right question yet.  I have tried the default as well as the current datasource.url, I've tried embedded H2 with a file (I see the items.mv.db file appear where it should but the console didn't find it nor did the IntelliJ database tools).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: H2 is in memory DB , that is if you shutdown the app the data is lost ,
are you sure that you are not shutting down you app and then restarting the app between these two changes ?ALso it seems you are using spring dev tools if you add a new class dev tools restarts the application and h2 data will be lost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the `application.properties` file, add this line to turn off the conflicting automatic schema creation:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

you can read more about it here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.0.M1/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html

Comment: I was hopeful after reading the link, I thought that it would have defaulted to none but apparently I was wrong.  Unfortunately this did not seem to fix it either.

Comment: I went back and tried it again and it worked.  I also combined both .sql files into a single file which may or may not have contributed to solving the problem.  I'm not sure what happened the first time I tried but it appears that this is a required part of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Points to remember :

1. H2 is an in-memory DB . that is if you re-start you application the existing data will be lost .
2. you have spring dev tools in your dependency , that restarts the app when you do a change/add/modify class/anything in your application .

based on your comment :-

> However. . .
>
> If I try to add an Item.java file like this (note if I comment out the
> @Entity line it works as shown above)

It seems that you are adding the data first via H2 console and then adding/modifiying the class ,
if you add/modify  the class after insertion of Data : spring dev tools will restart your app and your h2 data will be lost .

the recommendation is add the entity class and after that add data to the h2 db ,and make sure not to change anything in project after adding the data.

Comment: I rebuilt after adding the Item.java file and was not able to see the database in the h2-console.  If I comment out the @Entity line and build everything works as expected.  I can't seem to find what it's doing that H2 doesn't like though.